# PageTransition Using AnimatedBuilder Returns Black Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am getting a black screen on 'PageRouteBuilder' and I have no clue why. I was hoping someone can shed some light

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
        PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondAnimation) {
      return TestPage();
    }, transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondAnimation, child) {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animationController,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Transform(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
                ..rotateY(3.14 * _animation.value),
              child: child,
            );
          });
    }));
```

Comment: is there any error in your console when the black screen appears?

Comment: No errors in console which is why I'm so confused

Comment: I only encountered this black screen when my second page was only a single container. also do you get the same result with a simple `MaterialPageRoute` ?

Comment: My second page is a scaffold widget with back button in the appbar and just a container supplying the background color. I'm only trying to test functionality of this page transition. I am trying to animate page transitions which is why I am using the 'PageRouteBuilder'.

Answer (score 0):

The Transform widget gets child from AnimatedBuilder, that doesn't have one.
Just pass child argument of transitionsBuilder to AnimatedBuilder constructor or rename child argument of AnimatedBuilder.

```
  return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, _) {
        return Transform(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
            ..rotateY(3.14 * _animation.value),
          child: child,
        );
      });
```